# special characters in title tag

Tags: javascript, html

How do you enter special characters in the title attribute of html?

My JavaScript code:

```
var link_english = document.createElement("img");
   link_english.setAttribute("src", "images/english_out.png");
   link_english.setAttribute("title", "The english version of Nauma.com"); // 
   link_english.className = "classEnglish";
```

My question is: How do I insert a special tag within the value of the title attribute?

Example:

```
link_english.setAttribute("title", "here I want to put a special character for a German letter, the " ü " ");
```

If it is a normal html file, no problem.

Comment: What special characters?

Comment: In what context? I don't understand. Please add more detail.

Answer (score 4):

Just enter them.

You only need to ensure that the HTML page is saved using a character encoding which supports those characters (UTF-8 is preferred if you want world domination) **and** that the HTML page is been served over HTTP with a `Content-Type` header which signifies the very same character encoding, so that the browser understands how to display them to the human, e.g `text/html;charset=UTF-8`.

How to save the files the right way depends on the editor used, but usually this is available by *Save As* function and/or in the general editor settings. How to set the right HTTP content type header depends on the programming language and/or webserver used.

---

**Update**: the above answer still applies on your update. Save/serve file as UTF-8 and instruct browser by `Content-Type` header to interpret it as UTF-8. This applies on JS files as good as on HTML files and other text based files.

Comment: +1. If, for whatever reason, you *can't* ensure the page is served correctly in the first place (which is the right thing) -- a bad hosting company, whatever -- you can throw the browser a bone with `<meta charset='UTF-8'/>` (UTF-8 or whatever encoding you're using). More: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/semantics.html#attr-meta-charset

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can but to enter special character you have to use its HTML entity. [Here](http://www.utexas.edu/learn/html/spchar.html) is the table for special characters and its HTML entity.

Comment: You actually don't have to do that, that's just something a lot of people do because of the war between character encodings. If you just set the encoding of your html page to UTF-8 you can enter any character you want without the HTML entity code.

Comment: Its good practice to entity them anyway. If your document title is coming from user input (via a database for example) the user could enter "</title>", and without encoding it would disrupt your HTML document